# Executing multiple statements in database adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

To create a table in Rails 4 a database adapter should implement `visit_TableDefinition` and return an SQL string from it. Problem is, I also need to create a `SEQUENCE` and the DB driver in use (`ruby-oci8`) can't execute multiple statements for some reason. Is there a way to solve this?